# Kendo UI Adaptive Widget not changing to scheduler

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I copying the sample from Kendo Adaptive Widget page directly and it doesnt work I keep getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'kendoScheduler''
```

this is my view

```
<div data-role="view" id="barberDashboard" data-layout="default" class="signup-view" data-model="app.BarberDashboard" data-init="app.BarberDashboard.init"><!-- data-show="app.BarberDashboard.show" data-hide="app.BarberDashboard.hide">-->
    <header data-role="header">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            Dashboard
            <a class="nav-button nav-button-back hide-text" data-align="left" data-role="backbutton" href="#welcome">Back</a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="scheduler"></div>
</div>
```

and this is my js to set the init() method

```
var barberDashboardViewModel = (function () {
        var init = function initScheduler() {
            $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
                                               date: new Date("2013/6/26"),
                                               startTime: new Date("2013/6/26 07:00 AM"),
                                               height: kendo.support.mobileOS.wp ? "28em" : 600,
                                               views: [
.... Shortened for beravity
```

but it never works.  I have the lasted kendo.mobile.min.js and related css added to the project.

i have tried this in several projects and versions and have never gotten it to work.  I don't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scheduler itself is part of the Kendo UI Web suite - you need to use kendo.all.min.js to get it working as a mobile adaptive widget.